# Qt: adapting signals / binding arguments to slots?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Is there any way to bind arguments to slots ala [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/bind/bind.html)?

Here's a for-instance.  I have a window with a tree view, and I want to allow the user to hide a column from a context menu.  I end up doing something like:

```
void MyWindow::contextMenuEvent (QContextMenuEvent* event) {
   m_column = view->columnAt (event->x());
   QMenu menu;
   menu.addAction (tr ("Hide Column"), this, SLOT (hideColumn ()));
   // .. run the menu, etc
}
```

I need to capture the index of the column over which the context menu was activated and store it in a member variable that is used by my window's `hideColumn` slot:

```
void MyWindow::hideColumn () {
    view->setColumnHidden (m_column, true);
}
```

What I'd really like is to be able to bind the column number to my slot when I create the menu so I don't need this member variable.  Basically the Qt equivalent of:

```
menu.addAction (tr ("Hide Column"),
                boost::bind (&MyWindow::hideColumn, this,
                             event->columnAt (event->x()));
```

Or even better yet adapting the [QAction::triggered](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qaction.html#triggered) signal and attaching it to the [QTreeView::hideColumn](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtreeview.html#hideColumn) slot, which takes the column index as an argument:

```
menu.addAction (tr ("Hide Column"),
                boost::bind (&QTreeView::hideColumn, view,
                             event->columnAt (event->x())));
```

Is any of this do-able?

Comment: Now that Qt 5 supports C++0x lambdas, all of this messiness can be disposed of.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the only way is to create a QSignalMapper object to do this. It's like an extra level of indirection that can be used to generate a new signal providing the column index.  It's a little bit clumsy IME, you can end up with lots of QSignalMapper objects hanging around all the time, but seems to be the best way at this time.  (Ideally, IMO, you would be able to just supply any value such as the column index to connect() which would get passed as an argument to the slot, but you can't.)

Comment: Yup. The QT signals are pretty low-level (in the current version at least, there might be hope in the far future ;). Actually they're text-based (just look inside a moc_xx.cpp file or how the SLOT/SIGNAL macros are defined.)

Answer (score 6):

[LibQxt](http://libqxt.org) makes this possible through QxtBoundFunction and QxtMetaObject (the former does not show up in their [documentation](http://doc.libqxt.org/0.5.0/) for some reason).  It's an Open Source project, so you can grab the source if you're interested in the implementation. It uses the following syntax:

```
connect(
    button,
    SIGNAL(clicked()),
    QxtMetaObject::bind(
        lineEdit,
        SLOT(setText(QString)),
        Q_ARG(QString, "Hello World!)
        )
    );
```

[LibQxt](http://libqxt.org) has some other very useful features like the ability to [emit signals over a QIODevice](http://doc.libqxt.org/0.5.0/classQxtRPCService.html), such as network connection.

Answer (score 6):

Can't you use the `setData` function of the `QAction`?

```
void MyWindow::contextMenuEvent (QContextMenuEvent* event)
{
    m_column = view->columnAt (event->x());
    QMenu menu;
    QAction * action = menu.addAction (tr ("Hide Column"), this, SLOT (hideColumn ()));
    action->setData(QVariant(hideColumn));
}

void hideColumn()
{
    const QAction * action = qobject_cast<const QAction *>(this->sender());
    assert(action);

    int hide_column = action->data().value<int>();
    this->view->setColumnHidden (m_column, true);
}
```

Comment: Not bad.  Didn't know about setData.  Now that one can use C++0x lambdas in Qt 5, this messiness can all go away.  Yay!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment above, this is much easier in Qt 5 as you can connect a signal directly to a functor such as the result of std::tr1::bind() or boost::bind().  For Qt 4, there are a number of adapter libraries.  Kaleb mentioned LibQxt.  I have one at https://github.com/robertknight/qt-signal-tools